# How do I import Sidebar component?

Tags: typescript, next.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usw3P.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiprM.png)

And I get this error
Cannot find module '@components/Sidebar' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

I tried
import Sidebar from '@components/Sidebar'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'

Comment: Please don't use images for questions

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to export it? like this:

```
export const Sidebar: React.FC<...>
```